# Visitor visa to re-enter USA after 1 month in Mexico

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, visa-extensions

My mom came from Venezuela to visit my sister and my family and after 6 months we applied for an extension of stay, she went to Mexico to visit my nephew and his wife but I want her to come back to the USA; how long does she need to be outside before she can re-enter the state?

Comment: What happened with the extension of stay request? Does she have a valid vistor's visa now?

Comment: I am so sorry for the duplicate, my computer froze in the middle of asking the question. :(

Comment: I don't think the chosen duplicate question is valid because it's about someone from a  VWP country but this question isn't. Venezuelan citizens need an actual visa.

Comment: Her extension was approved to stay for the extra 6 months but before expiration, we took a trip to Mexico and she is there right now, her visa will expire in 2022

Answer (score 2):

If she has a valid US visitor visa, she can seek to enter the US at any time. There is no requirement of amount of time she needs to have been away from the US. However, the immigration officer at entry is more likely to deny her entry or admit her for a short period of time if the officer thinks that she has been to the US too much recently to be a visitor.

Comment: Her extension was approved to stay for the extra 6 months but before expiration, we took a trip to Mexico and she is there right now, her visa will expire in 2020.

Comment: Her visitor visa is good until 2022.